# Parquet and Data Duplication

Tags: hadoop, parquet

It's sur that parquet files make OLAP queries faster cause of it columnar format, but in the other side the datalake is duplicated (raw data + parquet data).
even if parquet can be compressed, dont you think that duplicating all the data can costs a lot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is depend on your use case. Duplication might be required if you need data for various reason, let say for staging data and for query.

Parquet is designed best for query, especially OLAP query which frequently involved certain column only. Meanwhile, it takes more time to write Parquet file than other file.

**In short, if both of your data is target of OLAP query, you might need to consider to have Parquet version of the file only.**

See this document for your reference. http://www.slideshare.net/StampedeCon/choosing-an-hdfs-data-storage-format-avro-vs-parquet-and-more-stampedecon-2015?qid=697d8f63-e6d8-4db1-951d-0f6f3b170ad1&v=default&b=&from_search=2